# neural networks - variance of gradients in minibatch

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, variance

I'm using tensorflow to try to investigate the local reparameterization trick [Kingma et al, 2015] and the effect it has on the variance of the gradients. I'm getting strange results however and I'm concerned I may be misunderstanding what's going on.

My understanding is as follows: given a loss function or lower bound etc. it's possible to compute a matrix of derivatives for each data point which is the derivative of this loss function with respect to each weight in the weight matrix for the output layer (if these are the gradients we want to examine). For any one of these weights, the variance is calculated across the derivative of the loss function for each data point with respect to this weight. So if we start with a (1000, 1000) weight matrix, we finish with a (1000, 1000) matrix whose entries (i,j) are given by the variance across the derivatives of the loss function for each datapoint in the mini-batch with respect to weight (i,j).

At this point we can take the mean of all variances in the matrix to give us the final average variance. Is this what's being referred to when people talk about the variance of the gradients?

Comment: This [question on Crossvalidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244352/variance-of-gradient-as-e-g-in-sgd?rq=1) deals with the same issue. The calculation will be done in the way you describe, but the interpretation is via the trace of the variance matrix.

Comment: I'm not sure what is the variance matrix in this case? For each training example we generate a matrix whose entries (i,j) are the derivative of the loss function for that data point wrt weight (i,j)